# Laptop sold with "Windows 7 Pro 64-Bit/Windows 8.1 Pro Downgrade", possible to upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10

For whatever reason this laptop sells with a Windows 7 Pro 64-Bit preinstalled which is actually a downgrade from Windows 8.1 Pro.

Now, will I still get the free Windows 10 upgrade with this constellation?

If possible, could you please backup your answer with sources?

Comment: All users with a legitimate Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 license are eligible to upgrade to Windows 10 for free until July 29th 2016.   You can read more [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade).

Comment: Someone from Microsoft, or a Microsoft fanboy deleted my comments... It just shows you how much they want you to upgrade to Spyware 10, ahem, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible.  Regardless of whether you are running 7 or 8.1, you are entitled to the free windows 10 upgrade.  See:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/upgrade-to-windows-10-faq

If you have downgraded from 8.1 to 7, installed SP1 (plus hotfixes) and have activated windows, you are seen as having a "genuine, activated copy of 7/8.1" - meaning you should be perfectly ok to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather say that :

- If your windows is genuine (shows as activated).
- Try the upgrade through windows media creation tool.
- Choose edition as windows 10, click confirm and choose your language confirm then it will redirect to download page , download your system specific version(32 or 64 bit).
- Run the tool.
- When it ask to **create media** check the **upgrade** option instead.
  It has two benefits :
- It does not do any harm to your computer neither it does any corruption or any other issue on the current system.
- It would verify the eligibility for your system. whether you can do or not.
  The download link from Microsoft is :
  [Media creation tool for windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO)

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is possible. If you have genuine copy of Windows, you will get Windows 10 app automatically and if not you can download the iso from Microsoft website.

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an actual answer.